# Factorization of vector valued function

Tags: calculus, matrices

Matrix valued function $\mathbf A$ is a solution of second order linear differential equation: $d^2 \mathbf A /dt^2+\mathbf {R A} = 0$ with initial conditions: $\lim_{t\to 0} \mathbf A = 0$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} {d \mathbf A}/{dt}= \mathbf I$. And also $\mathbf A$ is nonsingular for $t\neq0$.

Vector valued function $\mathbf Z$ is $\mathcal C^2$ and 
$\lim_{t\to0}\mathbf Z = 0$, show that it can be factored as:
$$ \mathbf Z=\mathbf A \mathbf W$$, where $\mathbf W$ is $\mathcal C^1$ at $t=0$.

It is easy to see that
$\lim_{x\to0} \;2(d\mathbf A/dt)(d\mathbf W/dt)+A(d^2\mathbf W/dt^2)$
 is defined, but how to prove that limits of each term exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{A}$ solves an ODE, and so is at least $C^2$ (in fact, if $\mathbf{R}$ is a constant matrix, you know that the solution is real analytic), and you know it is non-singular away from $t = 0$, so that when $t \neq 0$ the object $\mathbf{W} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{Z}$ is well-defined and $C^2$. So your question is mainly showing that this vector has a $C^1$ extension to $t = 0$.

First you need to show continuity. This follows essentially from L'Hopital's rule. Since $\mathbf{A}$ solves the ODE, you know that

$$ \mathbf{A}(0) = 0, \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{A}(0) = \mathbf{I}, \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}(0) = 0 $$

so

$$ \mathbf{A}(t) = t\mathbf{I} + O(t^3) $$

which implies that

$$ \mathbf{A}^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{t} (\mathbf{I} + O(t^2)) $$

So the limit

$$ \lim_{t \to 0} \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Z} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac1t \mathbf{Z} + O(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{Z}(0) $$

since $\mathbf{Z}(0) = 0$.

To show that $\mathbf{W}$ is differentiable at $t = 0$, you need to compute

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t} \left( \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{Z} - \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{Z}(0)\right) $$

The previous computation has already shown that the difference in the parentheses is $O(t)$. But we can Taylor expand a bit more and write

$$ \mathbf{A}(t) = t \mathbf{I} + \frac{t^3}{6} \mathbf{R} + O(t^4) $$

and

$$ \mathbf{Z}(t) = t \dot{\mathbf{Z}}(0) + \frac{t^2}{2} \ddot{\mathbf{Z}}(0) + o(t^2) $$

Therefore

$$ \mathbf{A}^{-1}(t) \mathbf{Z}(t) = (\mathbf{I} - \frac{t^2}{6} \mathbf{R} + O(t^3)) \cdot (\mathbf{Z}(0) + \frac{t}{2} \ddot{\mathbf{Z}}(0) + o(t)) $$

or

$$ \mathbf{A}^{-1}(t) \mathbf{Z}(t) = \dot{\mathbf{Z}}(0) + \frac{t}{2}\ddot{\mathbf{Z}}(0) + o(t) $$

showing continuous differentiability at $t = 0$.